# Links not showing up on "AMPforWP"

Tags: mobile

When people go to my webpage on mobile, none of the links work they're just straight text. How can I force my mobile page to keep the links that I have provided?

Comment: Sounds like a bug - you may need to contact the plugin author for help troubleshooting, or try a different AMP plugin.

Answer (score -1):

i didn't use this plugin but if i were you i use .htacces to redirect mobiles users to amp url

Assuming your amp version is under /amp (http://example.com/amp), you can try redirecting your visitors in your .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/amp$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|googlebot\-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|\#opera\ mobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([\/]*)$ https://example.com/$1/amp [L,R=302]
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171028/how-can-i-redirect-to-amp-version-of-website-on-mobile

BTW google automatic use amp url if its detect AMP version on your website

for testing purpose open new tab and press F+12 and the upper left corner click mobile button and select any device and refresh and search your website whole URL in same tab so you can see how your website looks in google search.
you should wait at-least 7 days after updating your website structure